# Why two derivatives do not match

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Let $$
\begin{align}
u = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{r} \cosh(t) & \text{if } r\gt 0\\
\sqrt{-r} \sinh(t) & \text{if } r \lt 0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align} \tag 1 $$
and
$$  
\begin{align}
 v = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{r} \sinh(t) & \text{if } r\gt 0\\
\sqrt{-r} \cosh(t) & \text{if } r \lt 0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align} \tag 2
$$

Combining both $(1)$ and $(2)$ and using $\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1$, $ u^2 - v^2=r \tag 3$
Using $(1)$, $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\cosh(t)}{2\sqrt{r}} \text{ if } r\gt 0 \quad \lor \quad  -\frac{\sinh(t)}{2\sqrt{-r}} \text{ if } r\lt 0$$
However, using $(3)$, 
$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}= \frac{1}{2u} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{r}\cosh(t)}\text{ if } r\gt 0 \quad \lor \quad \frac{1}{2\sqrt{-r}\sinh(t)}\text{ if } r\lt 0$$

Why don't both of the derivatives of $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}$ match? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use partial derivatives when implicitly differentiating; you must use the total derivative. Otherwise you "miss" the fact that $v$ is **not** independent of $r$:
$$2u \frac{du}{dr} - 2v \frac{dv}{dr} = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking of $r$ in $(3)$ as a function of $u$ and $v$, ie  $r(u,v)=u^2-v^2$, so that 
$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}} = \left( \frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{u}} \right)^{-1} = (2u)^{-1} $$ 
So is the above incorrect? How do I know which is a function of which?

Comment: Yes, it’s incorrect. When you have multiple variables that depend on each other you have to be *very* careful to correctly keep track of what your are differentiating with respect to and what you are holding constant, and when to take a partial vs total derivative.

Comment: In particular $$\frac{dr}{du} = 2u - 2v\frac{dv}{du} = 2u- 2v \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}\frac{dr}{du}.$$ Note the extra terms.